# Rails - Display a title only once in an .each block

Tags: ruby-on-rails-3, iteration, block

Noob question here :)

I'm testing a variable, and if it exists, I'd like to display an .each loop with a title.
Of course, the title should be displayed only once. **Is there a way to do it? Any best practice**?

```
<%
@twitter_friends.each do |u|
  if @user = User.is_a_member?(u.id)
%>
    # HERE I'D LIKE TO DISPLAY THE TITLE ONLY AT FIRST ITERATION
    <% @user.name %> is your twitter friend, and is a member.
  <% end %>
<% end %>
```

Thanks !

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would normally recommend using `each_with_index` and checking for a zero index, but seeing as you have a conditional in the loop, you should use a check variable like so:

```
<% shown_title = false %>
<% @twitter_friends.each do |u| %>
  <% if @user = User.is_a_member?(u.id) %>
    # HERE I'D LIKE TO DISPLAY THE TITLE ONLY AT FIRST ITERATION

    <% unless shown_title %>
      <h1>My Title</h1>
      <% shown_title = true %>
    <% end %>

    <% @user.name %> is your twitter friend, and is a member.
  <% end %>
<% end %>
```